# How can I sort array elements by number of divisors?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, sorting

My problem is that I hit an obstacle while I was solving some exercises.
The source of the problem is that I have to write a program which sort descending an array by the number of each element's divisors, but when two element has the same number of divisors it should sort ascending those values.
My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int cntDiv(int n)   //get number of divisors
{
    int lim = n;
    int c = 0;
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < lim; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
        {
            lim = n / i;
            if(lim != i)
                c++;
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("in.txt");
    int n, i, j;
    fin >> n;
    int v[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fin >> v[i];

    int div[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        div[i] = cntDiv(v[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(div[i] < div[j] && div[i] != div[j]) //if the number of divisors are different
            {
                int t = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = t;

                t = div[i];
                div[i] = div[j];
                div[j] = t;
            }
            if(div[i] == div[j] && v[i] > v[j]) //if the number of divisors are the same
            {
                int t = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In.txt:

```
5
12 20 4 100 13
```

Output:

```
100 12 20 4 13
```

Although it works fine with this one and many other. For bigger inputs it exceeds the time limit which is `0.1s`. Any advice how should I rewrite the sorting? (I wrote bubble sort because I could not implement sorting array by property via quicksort)

Comment: This is no consulting site. And there is no language C/C++. Your code is C++, not C! Re performance: you answered your question yourself already.

Comment: *"I could not implement sorting array by property via quicksort"* -- I don't understand what this means. Why couldn't you implement quicksort?

Comment: I actually could not understand anything. English is not his first language

Comment: If your program works correctly but exceeds a time limit, this is probably a "challenge problem". The idea with many of these is that the naive solution will take too long, and the *real* task is to find a slick way to solve it. That's the challenge.

Comment: You may use `std::sort` with custom comparer (and maybe an additional index vector).

Comment: Bubble sort is the laziest sort always avoid that.For c++ use inbuilt sort() that will improve your time to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of structures.  The structure would contain the original value and a container of divisors:

```
struct Number_Attributes
{
  int number;
  std::list<int> divisors;
};
```

You can then write a custom *comparator* function and pass to `std::sort`:

```
bool Order_By_Divisors(const Number_Attributes& a,
                       const Number_Attributes& b)
{
  return a.divisors.size() < b.divisors.size();
}
```

The sorting then becomes:

```
#define ARRAY_CAPACITY (20U)
Number_Attributes the_array[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
//...
std::sort(&array[0], &array[ARRAY_CAPACITY], Order_By_Divisors);
```

The generation of divisors is left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: The comparer is a little more complex: it should handle equal size of `divisors`.

Answer (score 0):

Reworking your code with `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> customSort(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ps;
    ps.reserve(v.size());

    // We don't have zip sort :/
    // So building the pair
    for (auto e : v)
    {
        ps.emplace_back(e, cntDiv(e)); 
    }
    std::sort(ps.begin(), ps.end(), [](const auto&lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        // descending number of divisors, increasing value
        return std::make_tuple(-lhs.second, lhs.first)
             < std::make_tuple(-rhs.second, rhs.first);
    });
    return ps;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v = {12, 20, 4, 100, 13};
    const auto res = customSort(v);

    for(const auto& p : res)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " ";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/FkFrYk)